# OpenStack Instances not running after server reboot

Tags: openstack

After a power cut at our premise, I tried to start the instances at OpenStack, but none of them started up successfully. What could be the issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Without knowing anything at all about your setup it's almost impossible to answer your question. If your storage backend is ceph it could be necessary to remove old locks held by compute nodes from the rbd images.

Comment: Start by checking error messages and log messages. If you don't understand them, [add them to the question](https://serverfault.com/posts/1062499/edit). In general, most probably one system component has not started correctly, or some component could not clean up locks of some sort like @eblock remarks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved with the following:

1. Start iscsid service (I found it stopped).
2. Restart libvirtd service.
3. Remove console.log file for each instance.
4. Start the instance with: openstack server start <instance_id>

Thanks.